# Which one is the correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can anyone please tell me which is the correct sentence among these:

> 1. Even though I couldn't speak to you, I'll be missing you.
> 2. Even though I can't speak to you, I'll be missing you.
> 3. Even though I don't speak to you, I'll be missing you.

Comment: Context? We'd appreciate your own thoughts on this question: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Answer (score 0):

All of these sentence are correct in their own sense. It is not possible to tell which of these is correct unless you provide the context/source.

> Even though I couldn't speak to you, I'll be missing you.

**Meaning:** Even though you **couldn't** speak, you will be missing her/him. You didn't had the chance to talk to her/him earlier, and so you couldn't talk to her.

> Even though I can't speak to you, I'll be missing you.

**Meaning:** This means that you can not talk to her. Either someone else restrained you from doing so or for some other reason.

> Even though I don't speak to you, I'll be missing you.

**Meaning:** This means that you don't talk to her. It is your choice to not to talk to her.